# Android Studio Check Box

Tags: java, android-studio, android-checkbox, type-parameter

I'm looking for help with this error:

> error: incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds CheckBox,View
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

...which I get when running this code:

```
public class CheckBox extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_box);

        CheckBox checkbox1 = new CheckBox();
        checkbox1 = findViewById(R.id.bx1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the checkbox because the returned form `findViewById`is generic

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_box);

    CheckBox checkbox1 = (Checkbox) findViewById(R.id.bx1);
}
```